# SSDT VS2015 Exception "The tab has been closed" When trying to publish

Tags: visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools

Using VS2015 while trying to either Publish or Generate Script I get the following error "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80042003 The tab has been closed"

[image: Publish Dialog]
[image: Error]

I have tried repairing SSDT using the install https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt204009.aspx

Any other ideas?

Comment: actually I found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771193/visual-studio-database-project-fails-to-publish-no-error-messages

Comment: Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38771193/visual-studio-database-project-fails-to-publish-no-error-messages Had to close all my tabs in VS